# How do i write these two different methods and test them

Tags: java, object

Write two methods called isBetterThan
a. The first one should take an int pts and return true if the player has more than pts
points and false otherwise.
b. The second method should take another Player object and return true if this player has
more points than the other player and false otherwise.
c. In a comment after this method explain why you cannot create another isBetterThan
method which takes another player object and returns the string “yes” if this player has
more points than the other player and the string “no” otherwise.

I have done the first one but do not know how to do the second one. I do not know how to call a new Player object as the input.

```
public class Player{
    private String name;
    private int points;
    private int level;
    public static final int MAX_LEVEL = 10;
    public static int finished = 0;

  public boolean isBetterThan(int value){
        if(value>points)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
     }
```

a method that would give me another isbetterthan method... I already have a main method that calls these methods for testing.

Comment: here are my constructors...

Comment: public Player(String n, int l){
  name = n;
  level = l;
 }
  
 public Player(String na){
  name = na;

Comment: Don't add relevant details as comments. Use [edit] option and place them directly in question.

Comment: Have you tried to implement the second method somehow?

Comment: Just create a `public boolean isBetterThan(Player otherPlayer)` method .

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
public boolean isBetterThan(int value){
```

allows you to do: `somePlayer.isBetterThan(5)` for example.

Now simply go in and add

```
public boolean isBetterThan(Player otherPlayer){
  if (this.points <= otherPlayer.points) ...
```

and add the kind of comparison/decision making you want to happen. In order to avoid code duplication, you could simply implement the method to

```
  return isBetterThan(otherPlayer.points)
```

But that leads to the question why you got two APIs doing similar things. I would it find more reasonable to **only** other a `isBetterThan(Player)` method. You see, your API that compares against a simple int value basically externalizes that view about "levels and points" to the outside world. So either the actual "is better than" is something that is really based on just that number, or it is more complicated.

Comment: @TBrown See my update. This is super basic stuff: **from within** the player class your code can access all fields of the player class. So even fields of a Player object that comes in as parameter to some method.